# Google Script (Forms) - Cannot Convert Array to Choice[]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have looking into this issue for a while, but have yet to find a suitable answer (most involve switching to setChoiceValues() rather than addressing the "Cannot convert Array to Choice[]" issue with setChoices([])).

While attempting to generate form sections and questions via Google Script, I ran into the issue of not getting my answer selections to go to specific pages based on the user's answer.  This appears to be the difference between setChoiceValues() and setChoices([]), with the latter allowing for page navigation as best as I can tell.

However, when attempting to put my array of new choices into setChoices([]), I get the error message "Cannot convert Array to Choice[]".  My code works fine otherwise, but I need to use setChoices([]) (it seems) in order to get the page navigation that I want.

How can I loop values into an array or other container and be able to make them appear as a Choices[] object?  How can I make something like this work?  It seems like it should be much easier than it is, but I cannot see the solution.

Below is a segment of my code that is causing the issue:

```
//Form - globally accessible 
var f = FormApp.openById(f_id);
//Date Iterator
var curr_date = 0;
//Time Iterator
var curr_time = 0;
//Array of Times
var Tchoices = [];
//Setting Time choices per date
while(curr_date < dates.length)
{
    Tchoices = [];
    curr_time = 0;
    //dates is an array of objects with both d's (single date) and t's 
    //    (array of times for that date)
    var d = dates[curr_date].d;
    var end_break = f.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Times for " + d);
    var f_time = f.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(d);
    while(curr_time < dates[curr_date].t.length)
    {               
        end_break = end_break.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
        Tchoices.push(f_time.createChoice(dates[curr_date].t[curr_time], end_break).getValue());
        curr_time++;
    } 
    f_time.setChoices([Tchoices]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some minor issues with the building of your MultipleChoise object:

```
  //Form - globally accessible 
  var f = FormApp.openById('someID');
  //Date Iterator
  var curr_date = 0;
  //Time Iterator
  var curr_time = 0;
  //Array of Times
  var Tchoices = [];
  //Setting Time choices per date
  while(curr_date < dates.length)
  {
      Tchoices = [];
      curr_time = 0;
      //dates is an array of objects with both d's (single date) and t's 
      //    (array of times for that date)
      var d = dates[curr_date].d;
      var end_break = f.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Times for " + d);
      var f_time = f.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      f.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(d);
      while(curr_time < dates[curr_date].t.length)   //verify this while not sure what you have inside your dates array
      {               
          end_break = end_break.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
          Tchoices.push(f_time.createChoice(dates[curr_date].t[curr_time])); //You cannot add a pagebreak inside the elements of a choiseItem array
          curr_time++;
      } 
      Logger.log(Tchoices);
      f_time.setChoices(Tchoices);
  }
```

Check the values for dates[curr_date].t.length inside the Loop I'm not sure how you constructed the array.
You cannot add a pagebreak inside the elements of a choiseItem array

Comment: For clarification: dates is an array of objects.  dates[0] has elements d (single date as a string, ex: "3/1/17") and t (array of times as strings, ex: ["6:30 AM - 7:00 AM", etc...]).  

The nested while loop is to generate the list of times per date, which is why the times while loop is inside of the date while loop.

I didn't realize that I couldn't use "end_break" as my go-to-page since it was adding a new Page Break item.   

After creating the Page Break item first, then assigning it to a variable as a Page Break item, it started working.  Thank you very much for your help!